# Is there a way to extract some columns using Python csv reader module?

Tags: python, csv

I can open and read a csv file and print the selected columns using CSV module. However, I could not extract a few columns and store it in a LIST using CSV module

My file has only 4 columns (Name, Team, College and Salary) and I just want to extract 2 columns, namely NAME and SALARY and then I compute all the salaries from the SALARY COLUMN. I am looking for a CSV module solution and not Pandas. This is a strange requirement.

Below are my codes:

```
import csv
with open('nba.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    data = []
    for row in reader:
        print(row['Name'], row['Salary'])
```

[image: NBA.csv]

Comment: you can do it pretty easily using pandas library

Comment: Do you wish to save it back in CSV? Or just compute the sum of the salaries? If so, you've done the hardest part, just set a `sum = 0` variable and in your loop do `sum += row['Salary']`

Comment: Hi frankie567, I want to store the 2 columns into a list called data and it will be used later.

Comment: Hi Sreekiran, Yes I have done it in Pandas.  Now, my requirement is CSV module and that is my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=['Name', 'Salary'])
```

Comment: Thanks. I know it can be done in Pandas and it is very straight forward. It is just that my requirement is CSV module.

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATE

If I understand correctly:

```
import csv

data = []
with open('nba.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        data.append({'name': row['Name'], 'salary': float(row['Salary'])})

print(sum(x['salary'] for x in data))
```

with `csv.reader()`

import csv

```
data = []
with open('test.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        data.append({'name': row[0], 'salary': row[3]})

print(sum(float(x['salary']) for x in data[1:]))
```

Comment: Thanks Kostas. Yes, your solution is working. Next question, can you replace csv.DictReader with csv.reader? Just curious.

Comment: @Tony yes you could do this with a few modifications. `DictReader` creates a dict-like object that you can use a key to use data on the other hand `csv.reader` is a list-like object that you have to use the number of the column. Hope I helped.

Comment: Hi Kostas, could you provide the syntax please? I could not find it anywhere else. Using your program, what can be modified.

Comment: yes, I tested your codes. The output is slightly out.

Comment: [{'name': 'Name', 'salary': 'Position'},
 {'name': 'Avery Bradley', 'salary': 'PG'},
 {'name': 'Jae Crowder', 'salary': 'SF'},
 {'name': 'John Holland', 'salary': 'SG'},

Comment: When using csv.reader, I just want the name and salary only without the headers. The image I posted above the same except without the headers and "Team" and "College" data.

Comment: Then probably you have a different delimiter between your columns so it took another column named `Position`. Try to change the delimiter to let's say `delimiter=';'`

Comment: If you do not want the headers better use the `DictReader`. Also in the second example if you just use `data = data[1:]` you remove the first element which are the headers.

Comment: Thanks Kostas, do you have a web link where I can learn more about DictReader? I want to search the data or remove based on certain criteria, remove or add more columns, etc.

Comment: Hi Kostas, for CSV.READER, how can I modify your codes to have the data for Name and Salary without the headers. Just 2 columns of data. Could you show me. No computation or display. I am very new to this.

Comment: @Tony this is the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: Thanks Kostas, I will take a look at it. Is this the only site that you have? I would like to have more examples.

Answer (score 1):

If performance is a concern you can use [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to get the columns that you want.

```
>>> igetter = operator.itemgetter(0, 3)
>>> with open('nba.csv') as f:
...     reader = csv.reader(f)
...     next(reader)   # Skip header row
...     data = [igetter(row) for row in reader]
... 
['Name', 'Team', 'College', 'Salary']
>>> data
[('Avery Bradley', '7730377'), ('Jae Crowder', '6796117'), ('John Holland', '1749840'), ('R. J. Hunter', '1148640')]

>>> total_salary = sum(int(salary) for _, salary in data)
>>> total_salary
17424974
```

`itemgetter` will also work with a `DictReader`:

```
>>> igetter = operator.itemgetter('Name', 'Salary')
>>> with open('nba.csv') as f:
...     reader = csv.DictReader(f)
...     data = [igetter(row) for row in reader]
... 
>>> data
[('Avery Bradley', '7730377'), ('Jae Crowder', '6796117'), ('John Holland', '1749840'), ('R. J. Hunter', '1148640')]
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't use Pandas unless the file is small. Pandas are super slow.

```
import csv
data_list = []
with open('nba.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        data_list.append([row['Name'], row['Salary']])
```